# React native: Can't import and use external packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, react-native

I am trying to use the react-native-tabbar-navigator package. I did 
`npm install react-native-tabbar-navigator --save` in my project directory to install the package. In my code, I have the following import lines to use the package.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {TabBarNavigator} from 'react-native-tabbar-navigator'
import MainTab from './MainTab';


import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
```

However, running this on my android simulator gives me the following error:

Seems you're trying to access 'ReactNative.Component' from the react-native package. Perhaps you meant to access 'React.Component' from the 'react' package instead?

If I remove the import line for the TabBarNavigator, the error goes away. Why is this happening?

I am using version 0.3.0 of tabbarnavigator and 0.31.0-rc.0 version of react-native

Comment: what version of TabBarNavigator are you using?

Comment: I am using version 0.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that library is outdated, it won't work till they release a new version.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/DickyT/react-native-tabbar-navigator/blob/master/MainNavigator.js), `TabBarNavigator` is importing `Component` from `'react-native'` which is not supported on `react-native` v0.26+ .

You can manually change that in your local package(`node_modules`),

replacing

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TabBarIOS
} = React;
```

to this

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TabBarIOS
} from 'react-native';
import {Component} from 'react'
```

in **MainTabBar.js** and **MainNavigator.js**.

Anyway it would be easier for you to install an updated library like [react-native-tab-navigator](https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native-tab-navigator).